# What is this pink flowering alpine shrub?

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs

What's the name of this plant and where can one find it? The picture is taken in the Austrian Alps in maybe 2500m.

*Click image for full size*

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like [*Rhododendron ferrugineum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhododendron_ferrugineum), or alpenrose. This plant can be found in European mountain ranges in high altitudes, mainly above the tree line. Here's a similar picture I've found, for comparison:

[image]